# Progress bar doesn't show up on API 24

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I'm probably missing something super obvious. I've been trying for two hours to simply show a progress bar with indeterminate progress

this is my layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginForm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/smallMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



        </LinearLayout>


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margim"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />



        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
              />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**So far my code is just loading the layout.xml**

Everything appears nice as in the layout designer, BUT THE PROGRESS BAR DOES NOT.

Does anyone have ideas?
I followed 3 different tutorials and nothing

============================UPDATE==========================

I downloaded the API 27 image and it worked fine on emulator... but my app is targeting API 21

My cellphone is 24 and it doens't show the progress bar

Comment: Check that your phone's animation is enabled and set to `x 1` in the dev options.

Comment: Did I understand you right?  You have tested the code on only one real device?

Comment: @Jantzilla, if you put that info as an answer I can mark it as right!! it still got a bit different of emulator (faster) but i showed

Comment: Sounds Good @RafaelLima. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your phone's animation is enabled and set to `1x` in the `System Settings/Developer Options`.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a little more information on why this works? I'm curious if this is just due to debug issues or could there be an issue with a released apk.

Comment: My understanding is simply that the default indeterminate progress is an animation and making sure phone animation is enabled ensures function. I assume this to be a debug issue.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and I will pack this bit of information away for future use should I ever encounter the same issue.